# Difference between middleware and service provider in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Service providers add services to the application container during bootstrap, while middleware... ?

Comment: Think of middleware as request filters. Service providers are... well things that provide services (loosely speaking factories although that's oversimplifying it). There's a world of difference on what the role of each is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Middlewares could form a chain between the request/your controller execution/response.

They got the request/response references so they are free to modify the request/response. You could log something, modify the response, redirect, etc.

It could form chains like these:

1. -> request -> providers -> middleware#1 -> middleware#2 -> controller method -> middleware#3 -> response
2. -> request -> providers -> middleware#1 -> redirect

Service providers are pretty different. When your application bootstraps, it calls the registered service providers. Those providers can register instances to the IoC container, console commands, view composers and so on.

Comment: so middleware comes after providers, make sense why defining a view composer with variables dependent on middleware's data, does not work. Thanks @Tacsiazuma

Answer (score 1):

as the name suggests, middleware are usually in the middle of request & response (example custom authentication). Keep in mind they are called always if defined means if there is something which you need to do always they can be pretty handy.

Service providers in action do similar things but dont rely on request/response but app bootstrap time i.e. initialisation process.

Answer (score 0):

**Service providers** are responsible for bootstrapping all of the framework's various components, such as the database, queue, validation, and routing components.

**Middleware** provide a convenient mechanism for inspecting and filtering HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware that verifies the user of your application is authenticated.